# Как к введенным пользователем данным приписать то или иное значение

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
А=input()
# как теперь к этому А приписать ноль в начале, если это строка.
```

Пример:

```
Ввод:
1:15 РМ
Необходимое значение:
01:15 РМ
```

Comment: `A = "0" + A` что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, в общем вот код который получился

```
import re

input_data = input("")
#input_data = "1:45 PM"

pattern = r"[0-9]:[0-9][0-9] PM"
#pattern = r"1:45 PM"

if re.match(pattern, input_data):
    result = "0{0}".format(input_data)
else:
    result = input_data


print(result)
#result = "01:45 PM"
```

Код сделан с учетом того что тебе нужно будет определить нужно ли добавлять нолик к началу строки. Но если тебе не нужны эти формальности то можно просто использовать

```
A = "0" + A
```